# getText from JTextField in 1 class and place it on a label in the other

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield

I have one class `Names` and it has a JTextField. I am trying to place `getText` from this textfield and save it in the variable `nameString1`. I then want the other class `Game` to call `Names` and place the string collected from ``the JTextField onto a label. For some reason it is not displaying. Please let me know if there are any rookie errors, I am only year 10.

Names

```
package com.aqagame.harrykitchener;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Names 
{

    private JLabel player1Label;
    private JTextField player1Input;
    private JButton nextButton;
    public String nameString1;

    public Names()
    {
        final JFrame window = new JFrame("Player 1 username");
        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

        player1Label = new JLabel("Player 1");
        player1Input = new JTextField();
        nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        firstPanel.add(player1Label);
        firstPanel.add(player1Input);
        firstPanel.add(nextButton);

        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                nameString1 = player1Input.getText();
                System.out.print(nameString1);
                Names2 names2Call = new Names2();
                window.dispose();
            }
        });

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);
        window.setSize(250, 150);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Names();
            }
        });
    }   

}
```

Game

```
package com.aqagame.harrykitchener;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Game 
{

    private JLabel player1Str, player2Str;

    public Game()
    {

        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1))
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                int width = getWidth() / 4;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, 700);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, 700);
                }
            }
        };

        Names namesCall2 = new Names();
        player1Str = new JLabel(namesCall2.nameString1);
        drawPanel.add(player1Str);




        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: There's just too much code here. Post a smaller example that still replicates your problem. Also known as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I am not sure how I could shorten it, `Game` has the 2D graphics as I feel this may be relative to my problem. I will remove `Names2` as it is near enough the same as `Names`.

Comment: Call super.paintComponent or be prepared for some really cool weirdness

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the label without getting the textfield text. The JLabel on your Game wont change by the time you click the button..

Okie I made some change in you classes What I did is that I maid an interface which will be called when your button is pressed

**Here is the interface:**

```
 public interface Lawl {

    public void changename(String name);

}
```

**I then implemented this interface to the game:**

```
public class Game implements Lawl
{

    private JLabel player1Str, player2Str;
    JPanel drawPanel;
    Names namesCall2;
    public Game()
    {

        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        drawPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1))
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                int width = getWidth() / 4;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, 700);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, 700);
                }
            }
        };
       // Names namesCall2 = new Names(this);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                namesCall2 = new Names(Game.this);
            }
        });




        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void changename(String name) {
        System.out.println("I am clicked");
        player1Str = new JLabel(name);
        drawPanel.add(player1Str);  
        drawPanel.revalidate();
    }

}
```

In the names class:

```
public class Names 
{

    private JLabel player1Label;
    private JTextField player1Input;
    private JButton nextButton;
    public String nameString1;

    public Names(){}
    public Names(final Lawl game)
    {
        final JFrame window = new JFrame("Player 1 username");
        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

        player1Label = new JLabel("Player 1");
        player1Input = new JTextField();
        nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        firstPanel.add(player1Label);
        firstPanel.add(player1Input);
        firstPanel.add(nextButton);

        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                nameString1 = player1Input.getText();
                System.out.print(nameString1);
                game.changename(nameString1);
               // Names2 names2Call = new Names2();
                window.dispose();
            }
        });

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);
        window.setSize(250, 150);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

**How it works??**

I created an interface and implemented it to the game class then pass the reference of the interface  to the Names class which will then be called when button is clicked..

when it is called `game.changename(nameString1);`by the button clicked it will then be called on the game class as you could see there is an method from the implemented inteface in the game class that will be called when you click the button..

If you want to chain data dont create a new Main thread to just execute a new Window.. just use the one I did in the code..

Comment: How could I change it to work? I am also curious about the `Game` class as I am calling it under the 2D graphics, will this cause any issues?

Comment: @HarryKitchener updated answer please check it it works on mine

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
public final static JTextField player1Input;
```

instead of

```
private JTextField player1Input;
```